# How does calling interface methods auto-call derived class methods in C#?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface

Given the following example from pluralsight on dependency inversion, I am extremely confused as to how this works. So we are given the following interface and a derived class implementation.

```
public interface INotifyCustomer
{
    void NotifyCustomer(Cart cart);
}

public class NotifyCustomerService : INotifyCustomer
{
    public void NotifyCustomer(Cart cart)
    {
        string customerEmail = cart.CustomerEmail;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(customerEmail))
        {
            using (var message = new MailMessage("orders@somewhere.com", customerEmail))
            using (var client = new SmtpClient("localhost"))
            {
                message.Subject = "Your order placed on " + DateTime.Now;
                message.Body = "Your order details: \n " + cart;

                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Error("Problem sending notification email", ex);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The part that I cannot wrap my head around is the idea that simply calling the interface as shown below somehow calls the derived class without ever instantiating or even mentioning that derived class. Example below:

```
public class Order
{

    private readonly Cart cart;
    private readonly PaymentDetails paymentDetails;
    private readonly INotifyCustomer notifyCustomer;

    public Order(Cart cart, PaymentDetails paymentDetails, INotifyCustomer notifyCustomer)
    {
        this.cart = cart;
        this.paymentDetails = paymentDetails;
        this.notifyCustomer = notifyCustomer;
    }
    public void Checkout(Cart cart, PaymentDetails paymentDetails, bool notify)
    {
        if (paymentDetails.PaymentMethod == PaymentMethod.CreditCard)
        {
            ChargeCard(paymentDetails, cart);
        }

        ReserveInventory(cart);

        if (notify)
        {
            notifyCustomer.NotifyCustomer(cart);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with an explanation? I'm not exactly new to C# but haven't been using it too long, I've been more of a java person the last couple of years and I know there are fundamental differences between C# and Java. But I cannot see how or why this works?

Comment: You're missing the _injection_ part of dependency injection.  In your constructor, you will pass in the concrete class instance (or better yet use an IOC container to do it for you)

Comment: Somewhere, a `NotifyCustomerService` *is* created, since it *implements* the interface, the code shown only cares that the object passed *has* the function it wants to call (there is no magical forwarding: the object passed has the method implemented).

Comment: @maccettura is correct. Although you have INotifyCustomer as the type for the third argument in the Order constructor, only an object that implements INotifyCustomer can be provided as that argument. In such a case, there must be a definition for the NotifyCustomer method of that object, since the interface requires it.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused because @maccettura the injection is in fact there, by injecting INotificationService via the constructor they call it later in the Checkout method. This is source code from pluralsight as well, I did not write this code just trying to wrap my head around it. And crashmstr you're definitely right, because the code works, but where along the lines is NotifyCustomerService being created? As the INotificationService calls its NotifyCustomer method? Does it then realize that the implemented method is within a derived class?

Comment: I know the injection is there, I only meant you are missing the _concept_ of injection.  The reason it works is because your constructor has to be called with an instance of `INotifyCustomer ` (or technically null I guess).

Comment: @maccettura I see what you are saying now I think, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though this question does not really have a definitive "answer" (likely too broad of a scope for SO), I still wanted to post an answer to hopefully help cement the idea of dependency injection.

Consider this:

From now on, every bit of code you write will only reference *abstracts* of your objects.  Abstracts meaning interfaces (or potentially abstract classes or base classes but thats outside of my point for now).

The benefit of this is that your code **does not care how the abstract is implemented**, all it knows or cares about is that the methods or properties it expects to be there are there.

This gives you a variety of benefits:

- Your code becomes more modular because you can easily swap out concrete implementations by injecting a different dependency.
- You can have "Mock" classes to coincide with actual classes (think of API services where you have an HTTP connection to worry about, now you can unit test other code by faking HTTP requests in a mock service).
- Etc, etc

I think the part that has confused you though is what you are perceiving as the "magic" of dependency injection. Your constructor has an argument of type `INotifyCustomer`.  When your `Order` class is instantiated those arguments **have** to be provided (yes I know a null can be passed technically).  Since we have already established that your code is absolutely **indifferent** to what is passed in, so long as its of type `INotifyCustomer` your code will just run as if you passed in the concrete directly (but now we have *all* the benefits of dependency injection).

Comment: This makes perfect sense, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @s.gang Somehow I messed up the link, [this should work](http://michelangeloaccettura.com/2017/06/27/demystifying-dependency-injection-in-dot-net/)

Answer (score 2):

Your interface implementation is a contract.  It simply says, "if you implement me (the interface), then you have to provide this method `NotifyCustomer` that takes a `Cart` and doesn't return a value (i.e. `void`).  If you implement it, you can do whatever you want in your `NotifyCustomer` method as long as you do the above.

Your class `Order` doesn't know what `notifyCustomer` is except that it implements `INotifyCustomer`.  Your compiler knows, though, so when the code compiles and runs, it actually calls your code in `NotifyCustomerService`.  By utilizing dependency injection, you can design code without caring or knowing how the dependencies are implemented as long as they satisfy the contract.

Comment: The *compiler* doesn't know what the actual implementation will be.  The *runtime* will know.  The whole point of the pattern is that the compiler *can't* know.  That said, you haven't actually answered the question asked, which is asking how the actual runtime object is linked to the code shown.

Comment: The compiler knows when it's being compiled unless reflection is being used, e.g. with an IoC container.  The compiler certainly can know, though.  And I have answered the question (it was just accepted).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I didn't realize that by using the dependency injection method you could set things up this way. I'm sure this is possible in Java I had just never seen it.

Comment: The whole *point* of virtual dispatch is that the compiler *doesn't* know.  It *can't* know.  It knows that there will be a valid implementation, but it doesn't know what it is.  That the OP accepted an incorrect answer that doesn't answer the question that they asked doesn't mean you answered the question that was asked, it just means that they don't *care* that it doesn't answer the question that they asked and that they don't *care* that it's incorrect.

Comment: I'm confused as to how you know exactly what I was looking for Servy, nonetheless he gave me an answer that actually made sense, whether or not it's the compiler or the runtime that know that's infact not what I was asking. But you seem just like the type of person to tell people what they are thinking so I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed nothing in your class `Order` instantiates `NotifyCustomerService`, but it knows that an object of type `INotifyCustomer` has a method NotifyCustomer with the specified parameters and return type. It doesn't have to know about how that method is implemented in the class `NotifyCustomerService`.